# Declare instance variable in Objective-C and set in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I want to be able to set the value of an instance variable from my Objective-C class in my Swift class. In my Swift class, I want to be able to say something like `cameraViewController.ingestViewController = self` and have that set the value of `ingestViewController` in my Objective-C class. Here is some code to demonstrate:

PhotoViewController.swift:

```
class PhotoViewController : UIViewController {
    let cameraViewController = // reference to the CameraViewController
    cameraViewController.ingestViewController = self
}
```

CameraViewController.h:

```
@interface CameraViewController : GSKCameraViewController

@end
```

CameraViewController.m:

```
@interface CameraViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *toolbar;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *cameraButton;
@property (class, nonatomic, strong) UIViewController *ingestViewController;

@end

@implementation CameraViewController

UIViewController *ingestViewController

// rest of implementation

@end
```

I continue to get the error `Value of type 'CameraViewController?' has no member 'ingestViewController'`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You've declared the `ingestViewController` property as a class property, not an instance property.

Remove the `class` attribute of the `@property`.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIViewController *ingestViewController;
```

Once that is fixes, you need to make the property public. Move it to the .h file:

```
@interface CameraViewController : GSKCameraViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIViewController *ingestViewController;

@end
```

All of the properties in the .m are private.

Lastly, remove the unnecessary line:

```
UIViewController *ingestViewController
```

from the .m file. That is actually declaring a global variable and is not in any way associated with the property of the same name.

Comment: I changed `@property (class, nonatomic, strong) UIViewController *ingestViewController;` to `@property (nonatomic, strong) UIViewController *ingestViewController;` and am still getting the same error.

Comment: Clean project, try to clean derived data and then build 1 more time.

Comment: Oh okay I got it now, thanks! I also didn't have a semicolon after `UIViewController *ingestViewController` in CameraViewController.m

Comment: Answer deserves to be accepted, .m file variables are not visible outside.

Comment: @jordan That line shouldn't even be there. Remove it.

Answer (score 0):

```
@property (class, nonatomic, strong) UIViewController *ingestViewController;
```

This is a class property, not instance variable property.
So just remove `class` attribute.